# Change GUICtrlCreateDate format in AutoIt?

Tags: date, automation, format, autoit

I'm trying to change the format of AutoIt's built in date picker. Currently, when I use the date picker, it will display the date in this format: Tuesday, October 27th, 2015 and I need it in this format: 10/27/2015. It would be preferable to allow access to each individual component of the date so I could change it later in the program.

This is what I have. I don't understand why it's not displaying the results in the desired format. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance!

```
GUICtrlCreateDate(@MDay & "/" & @Mon & "/" & @Year, 16, 16, 241, 33)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my own problem.

First, I needed to download Melba23's DTC.au3 file and include it in my script.

```
#Include "DTC.au3"
```

(https://www.autoitscript.com/forum/topic/154684-date_time_convert-bugfix-version-27-may-15/) (GREAT WORK ON THIS SCRIPT!). Then I created my date picker.

```
GUICtrlCreateDate(@MDay & "/" & @Mon & "/" & @Year, 16, 16, 241, 33)
```

Then right under that, I added this:

```
$sIn_Date = GUICtrlRead($addBillDate)
$sOut_Date = _Date_Time_Convert($sIn_Date, "dddd, MMMM d, yyyy", "MM/dd/yyyy")
$addBillDate = $sOut_Date
```

Now the date format is converted from Tuesday, October 27, 2015 to 10/27/2015

I figured I could post my solution just in case it helps somebody out.